# Why is iTunes duplicating my TV shows?

Tags: itunes

It seems every time I go into iTunes it's duplicated my TV shows again. I could understand if these were shows that I'd ripped from DVDs myself (maybe I'd made a mistake or something), but in the case of CHEERS (see below), all the episodes are purely bought through iTunes.

What's going on? :(

[image]

If you click on each of those Cheers you will see exactly the same episode listings across all three. Same goes for WINGS - identical listing. I can't fathom what's going wrong? :( Do I need to rebuild my iTunes database or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I rebuilt my entire iTunes library only to discover the problem was that I'd told iTunes to sort by year. Doh.

Quite annoying because I still want my programs to be listed by year... but not year by season. Hmm.

Comment: Hello and many thanks for taking a moment to post your solution.